# best version control system for personal/home use when developing with eclipse and python/django

Tags: python, eclipse, version-control

I am working on a small django project at home. I would like to install and use a small version control system for personal use for free. I don't want to use a web service like github because I am not always connected. I would like to have the VCS server/daemon installed and use it at my home pc (windows 7).

I would also like it to be compatible with eclipse+pydev which I use for programming.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GIT is built in a way that you can use it 'offline': doing commit, reverting change, browsing history.

I don't see any advantage in your case to use SVN instead of GIT (you can host your own GIT server, no need to use github.com)

http://book.git-scm.com/4_setting_up_a_public_repository.html

*There are also GIT alternatives for distributed SCM:*

- Mercurial
- Bazaar

---

BTW, for my personal prototype DropBox is sufficient ;)

Comment: It is only fair to mention at least Mercurial and Bazaar while pushing Git. For myself, used all four of these at least somewhat (Git least of all, thus far), I would recommend Mercurial over SVN as the most similar. Some features of git such as its mandatory staging area are just confusing to someone familiar with CVS, SVN, bzr or hg (unless the hg user had used mq).

Comment: @Chris Morgan What is 'fair' is totally subjective like my answer that is based on my own experience. Never used Mecurial or Bazaar, I moved directly from SVN to GIT.... I added alternatives you mention in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using mercurial with a Bitbucket private repository.  Mercurial will work just fine when you're offline, and you can push your changes to Bitbucket to access your code elsewhere (your laptop, server, etc.) later.

There's also mercurial plugins for eclipse. (see [Mercurial Eclipse Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629058/mercurial-eclipse-plugin))

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use Mercurial together with DropBox in order to make sure that you don't lose everything in case of crash.

See http://www.h4ck3r.net/2010/05/11/mercurial-hg-with-dropbox/

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

For [personal version control](http://www.foldertrack.com), I would recomend the following:

- [FileHamster](http://www.filehamster.com)
- [Oops! Backup](http://www.altaro.com)
- [FolderTrack](http://www.foldertrack.com)

Note: I am an author of FolderTrack. I recomend it for use with programming because it will treat a group of source files as one "work product". If you want to rewind your code to yesterday and that requires deleting 2 files, renameing 1 file, and chaning 15 more then foldertrack will do it.

The free license for Foldertrack is: BOS

Comment: Have tried Oops! Backup. Not for my needs. On the other hand FolderTack looks good. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[SVN](http://subversion.apache.org/) has Eclipse plugins ([Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/), [Subversive](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/)), I don't know for pydev though. But it is one of the most used version control system and it is free.

Comment: Other suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446292/personal-version-controller

Answer (score 0):

If it is for personal use, thus you probably don't have to go with distributed vcs, I would definitely go with subversion (svn). It has nice plugin for eclipse: subversive. I'm using it for years. 
http://subversion.apache.org/
for eclipse:
http://www.polarion.com/products/svn/subversive.php

Comment: Personally I use Mercurial for my own private stuff; rather than keeping the repository and working copy in separate directories as you do with SVN, it's all in the one place and can easily be cloned, pushed somewhere else, expanded upon, etc. There's lots of power in the DVCS design that is better than SVN which can be used without needing the "distributedness".